# ImportXML- xpathquery on a span class

Tags: html, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to use the `ImportXML` function to import **the price ($5.99)** of the following [website](https://www.target.com/p/trojan-sensitivity-ultra-thin-spermicidal-lubricant-condoms-12ct/-/A-11235054) into my google sheet.

I can't seem to identify the class name on the website to make it work. 
Currently using the following as my `xpath_query://div[@class='']`

I can't seem to get the correct `xpath_query` to point to the $5.99 using the `importXML` function.
Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I don't see that price. Can you include the html using the snippet tool via [edit] ? What is the product name?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that it's possible to access the price information with `IMPORTXML` because I believe the price data needs to be looked up every time the page is loaded, after some digging, I came across this page while inspecting the page:

[image: Found the price here]

That looks up the price using a very easily predictable (and therefore easily constructable) URL. The URL basically looks something like this:

https://redsky.target.com/web/pdp_location/v1/tcin/**[8 numbers]**?pricing_store_id=**[4 numbers]**&key=**[32 alphanumeric characters]**

So from back to front, the 32 characters at the end are some sort of key I believe, similar to a key one might use to access an API. I think this key is used to the program calling the requested information. The 4 numbers in the middle are some sort of store identification number. I would think that this is somehow used to pull pricing information for a specific store. And then perhaps most-importantly are those 8 numbers towards the front of that URL. I think these 8 numbers are the product identification information. It's sort of like a sku number.

Now, I did some testing and I came up with a very basic solution that will get the job done in most cases, without the use of any custom functions or scripting.

We can easily construct the price look-up URL based on nothing more than the URL of the product on the webpage. The 8 digit product identifier for the price lookup is the 8 digit string at the end of the URL you provided (and conveniently, this pattern is consistent across any product page).

As for the store identification number (4 numbers), it looks like we can actually set this to pretty much any value and it will work, so for my example, I will set it to 0000.

And now for that 32 key on the end. I tried without the key parameter ("&key=[key]") and I got an error that said the key parameter is required. However, for some unknown reason, I tried the same thing again, but I included the ("&key=") in the URL (just without the actual key), and it WORKED! It took me to the correct page.

So to recap, we just need the product number, which we can get from the URL (or any URL on Target.com).

Now, in Sheets we can import the data from this pricing URL with an `IMPORTDATA` call (note that `IMPORTXML` will not work in this instance). When we do so, we get something like this:

[image: Imported Data]

This will return a variety of columns with different pricing details. For this example I will assume we are interested in the "current_retail" price because it matched the price in your post.

From here, to get just the price, outputted as a string we can use the `INDEX` function, and remove the header with something like `SUBSTITUTE`. If we want the output to be interpreted as a number we just need to use the `VALUE` function on that.

Here is the final result:

[image: Table]

And here is the one function that powers it all:

```
=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(IMPORTDATA("https://redsky.target.com/web/pdp_location/v1/tcin/"&RIGHT(A2,8)&"?pricing_store_id=0000&key="),,5),"current_retail:",""))
```

We give it an input (the URL to the product), and it outputs the price as a number. This will work with other products too. However, sometimes there are issues with products that seem to have multiple prices, like for different size options and the like. In these instances, the array returned by `IMPORTDATA` looks a little different, which means the `INDEX` function may not be getting the right price data. There may be a solution to output the correct price, but that is beyond the scope of this answer.

Anyways, I hope this will help you find the prices of all the condoms you could ever want.